# Android AlertDialog Styling Issues

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have been fighting with a couple of issues with trying to style an alertDialog for a couple of days now. I have been searching around and tried many different methods but still cannot get it to work.

1) I cannot get the fontsize to change on the close button

2) I cannot get the text to center both horizontally and vertically on the button or the main message text

3) Is there a way to remove the box shadow?

4) Least important - I know I can set the theme to holo.light but I have been trying to change the background colour of the message box to white. Although I can do this by changing theme Id like to understand all of this a bit more

If anyone has any ideas on these issues then I would greatly appreciate any feedback. Thanks (code below)

styles.xml

```
<style name="G4STheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/G4S.AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/G4S.AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme_Holo_Dialog_Alert" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle_Holo</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogWindowTitle_Holo">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="G4S.AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/TextAppearance.G4S.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Widget.G4S.Button.Borderless</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/G4S.ButtonBar.AlertDialog</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.G4S.Button.Borderless</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialog_G4S">
    <item name="android:fullDark">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.G4S.DialogWindowTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.G4S.Medium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">156dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.G4S.Button.Borderless" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.G4S.DialogButton</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.G4S.DialogButton" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">40sp</item>
</style>

<style name="G4S.ButtonBar.AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Holo.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:background">#4aa3cb</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">96dp</item>
</style>
```

G4SAlertDialog.java

```
public class G4SAlertDialog extends DialogFragment {

AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    dialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.error_login_failed)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.error_login_dialog_close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // Dialog closed
                }
            });

    return dialogBuilder.create();
}
}
```

in activity to launch the dialog:

```
G4SAlertDialog failModal = new G4SAlertDialog();
failModal.show(getFragmentManager(), "acknowledgements");
```

Comment: Why all this code and effort when you can inflate a custom view for your AlertDialog easily?

Comment: Also if you want to edit the AlertDialog buttons style, you would better use a normal Dialog then. It's better and simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inflate custom layouts for your AlertDialog or Dialog. It's very simple, check this tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Create your `custom_dialog.xml`, then write in your code as shown in the tutorial link.

Hope that helps.